# Can the parent sign for in a minor's US DS-2019 form?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, minors, j1-visas

I recently received the DS-2019 form for the US J-2 visa application. The DS-2019 form is for my child (less than 14 yo) and requires signature by the applicant. Does this require:

1. either parent (principal applicant) sign, or
2. provide thumb impression, or
3. leave it blank

*What would be the correct choice for minor's DS-2019 form for J-2 visa application?*

Answer (score 5):

The DS-2019 form states on page 2:

> The J-2 spouse/dependents should sign the J-2 form under Signature of Applicant unless the J-2 dependent is under the
>   age of 14, in which case the J-1 exchange visitor, as the parent or legal guardian, must sign.

So you, as the person who is the J-1 visitor, should sign the J-2 DS-2019 form.

Answer (score 2):

I think they have changed the rule. Page 2 para 2 say, "Parent or guardian must sign the J2 form if accompanying minor is under 16."